# reactjs: execute a script only after render is complete after a certain part of state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have state like below:

```
this.state = {
data: [ .... ]
misc: [  .... ]
}
```

I have button when clicked it will fetch `data`.

the `data` will be fetched using `axios` and then `setState` is used to replace the `this.state.data`

Then as per reactjs `render will be called every time you setState to re-render the component if there are changes.`

After `this.state.data` is updated, and rendering is complete i want to run a function.

I dont want to run the function when `misc` is updated. I only want to update when `data` is updated

How to run a function after render only when this.state.data is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), which will be called after a component is mounted (first render) and [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), which will be called immediately after updating occurs (but not for the initial render).

`componentDidUpdate` takes 3 parameters: `prevProps`, `prevState` and snapshot. In your case, you can compare `prevState.data` against `this.state.data` to know whether `data` has been updated:

```js
class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.counter = 0;
    
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      misc: 'foo',
    };
    
    this.changeData = this.handleChangeData.bind(this);
    this.changeMisc = this.handleChangeMisc.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount!');
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.data !== this.state.data) {
      console.log('componentDidUpdate and data has changed!');
    }    
  }
  
  handleChangeData() {
    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data, this.counter++].slice(-10),
    });
  }
  
  handleChangeMisc() {
    this.setState({
      misc: this.state.misc === 'foo' ? 'bar' : 'foo',
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.changeData}>Change data</button>
        <button onClick={this.changeMisc}>Change misc</button>

        <pre>DATA = { this.state.data.join(', ') }</pre>
        <pre>MISC = { this.state.misc }</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 106px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict rendering on particular state change then just check for that state and return false else return true like:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

     if(this.state.misc != nextState.misc) {
          return false
     }
     return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you're talking about the use of lifecycle methods...

You should do your data fetching (ajax via axios or the native fetch api) in the `componenetDidMount` lifecycle hook

Something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });

  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(result => this.setState({ data: result.data, isLoading: false }))
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
}
```

And your updating in `componentDidUpdate` More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use componentDidUpdate (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). This is a lifecycle event that triggers every time the component updates, so you can check if the previous state of data is different than the current state. I'm assuming data is an array of objects, so to compare them you'll either have to use something to compare like _.isEqual from lodash, or what I've included below will work.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(JSON.stringify(prevState.data) !== JSON.stringify(this.state.data)) {
    // Execute your code
  }
}
```